# Agreement of the past participle in "C’est une raison que j’ai choisie"

Tags: grammaire, accord

Is there feminine agreement at the end of **choisi** in the sentence « C’est une raison que j’ai choisi »?

Comment: @None Yes, je vous remercie! I didn't see this one.

Comment: @fauna: If it does, and you don't have further questions, there should be [a prompt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/261498) from the system asking you if it answers your question, and you should be able to mark it as such so it's officially linked and closed (to keep threads for the same topic in one place).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The past participle must agree with the so called complément d'objet direct when the latter precedes the conjugated verb (in compound tenses like passé composé). 
See
http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/past_participle_agreements.shtml

In your case:

> C'est une raison que j'ai choisie...

I ain't natif speaker but the sentence sounds a little weird. We don't choose reasons I guess.

> C'est une raison pour laquelle j'ai choisi...

sounds more natural (to me at least). Note that here, due to pour, there is no agreement of the past participle (complément d'objet indirect).

**EDIT** (merci @None)

You cannot substitute C'est une raison que j'ai choisie... with C'est une raison pour laquelle j'ai choisi..., they carry different meanings. What is rather (but not impossible) weird is the use of the indefinite article in both sentences. Compare (a) C'est la raison que j'ai choisie de lui donner to (b) *C'est la raison pour laquelle je suis en retard".

Comment: 1- You cannot substitute *C'est une raison que j'ai choisie...* with *C'est une raison pour laquelle j'ai choisi...*, they carry different meanings. What is rather (but not impossible) weird is the use of the indefinite article in both sentences.  Compare (a) *C'est la raison que j'ai choisie de lui donner* to (b) *C'est la raison pour laquelle je suis en retard".  
2- When an answer already exists on FL we usually refer to it do not answer it again.

Comment: There is no direct object in sentence (b), so the question of agreement with a direct object  is irrelevant.

Comment: @None : Merci pour le retour. Je viens de modifier ma réponse. Je peux l'effacer sans aucun souci si nécessaire:-)!